To fix the 'locate' database. And to properly update it
I tried to update the locate database, and for some reason it has been corrupted:
locate foo

locate: locate database header corrupt, bigram char outside 0, 32-127: -1

How to repair it? Or maybe I need to just update it to make it work? And finally, back to the original problem, how to update it? (Yes, there are many answers about this, but hey, I tried only the most upvoted ones, and the database has been corrupted. It seems the answers were outdated or macOS has some issues here: most answers were for Linux.)
Sonoma 14.4.1, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

On MacOS, looking at the standard documentation tool man locate gives this snippet:

FILES
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb        Script to update the locate database
SEE ALSO … locate.updatedb(8)

But also

BUGS
… The locate utility does not recognize multibyte characters.

The "SEE ALSO" is referenced through man locate.updatedb:

DESCRIPTION The locate.updatedb utility updates the database used by locate(1). It is typically run once a week by the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist job.

First thoughts are that the multibyte issue may be what you're seeing. But it could be corruption too, so run the updater (as root) and then try again:
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb


Hello, Chris. Many thanks, sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb fixed the header corrupt problem. But why locate capture doesn't find the ~/Desktop/capture.mov file? Neither it finds the ~/Documents/foocapturebar folder. But it does find, for example, /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.corecaptured.plist. Does it mean that locate doesn't search in ~/ and its subfolders for some reason?

@jsx97 works for me. Did you create (or rename as) capture.mov before or after running locate.updatedb? Remember that locate database is a snapshot of the filesystem at the moment it's run, so it's really only a fast convenience over find / … for relatively static names. Similarly, date >today; sudo …locate.updatedb…; rm today; locate today will find the file today even though it no longer exists

Look at the file /private/etc/locate.rc. There are some options in here for paths and directories that are excluded/included.
